# A loan is to be repaid quarterly for five years that will start at the end of two years. If interest rate is $6$%..

Tags: economics

I was helping my comrade answer some questions when we found this question. It goes like this:

> A loan is to be repaid quarterly for five years that will start at the end of two years. If interest rate is $6$% converted quarterly, 
>   how much is the loan if the quarterly payment is $10000$?

**My work**

I recognize that the problem above is a deferred annuity problem. The payment will start at the end of two years (The payment is deferred 
by two years) and the payment will last five years.

The term "$6$% converted quarterly", I believe, would mean that the interest rate is $6$ percent per year divided by 4, giving $\frac{0.06}{4}$ or 
$0.015$. In short, the interest rate $6$% is compounded quarterly.

The amount of the loan to be paid for five years would be the present value of the loan at the end of five years. Using the formula

$$k|P = A(P/A,i\%,n)(P/F,i\%,k)$$
$$k|P = A \left(\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i(1+i)^n}\right) \left(\frac{1}{(1+i)^k} \right)$$

where....

$A$ is the amount of each payment of an ordinary annuity, $i$ is the interest rate, $n$ is the number of payment periods, and $k$ is the number of deferred periods

In this problem, we see that the number of payment periods if we pay quarterly for a year would be $4$. We will pay the amount for five years, so 
the number of payment periods is now $\left(\frac{4}{year}\right)(5 \space years) = 20 $. The number of deferred periods is $\left( \frac{4}{year} \right)(2 \space years) = 8$
because the interest rate already took effect even if there is no payment within the deferred period.

Now, we have...

$$k|P = A(P/A,i\%,n)(P/F,i\%,k)$$
$$k|P = A \left( \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i(1+i)^n}\right) \left(\frac{1}{(1+i)^k} \right)$$
$$k|P = A \left( \frac{\left(1+\left(\frac{0.06}{4}\right)\right)^{20}-1}{\left(\frac{0.06}{4}\right)\left(1+\left(\frac{0.06}{4}\right)\right)^{20}}\right) \left(\frac{1}{(1+\left(\frac{0.06}{4}\right))^8} \right)$$
$$k|P = 152407.91$$

Therefore, the present value of the loan after five years would be $\color{green}{152407.91}$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Isn't the period of deferral "7" instead of "8"?
Since it will start not "at the start of three years", but "at the end of two years".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.  Using actuarial notation, we have $$PV = 10000 \; {}_{8|} a_{\overline{20}| 0.015} = 10000 v^8 \frac{1 - v^{20}}{i^{(4)}/4},$$ where $i^{(4)} = 0.06$ is the nominal interest rate compounded quarterly, and $v = 1/(1+i^{(4)}/4)$ is the quarterly present value discount factor.

Answer (score -1):

If my claim is correct, thus:

period of deferral (k) is 7 quarters, or simply **7**.

By using:

**PVda = R((1-(1+j)^-n)/j)(1+j)^-k**

Explaining all of these variables is troublesome. So, use the formula given above. And, don't worry it will give you the same result.

Anyways...

just change that "8" to "7", and you'll get the correct answer **154,694.04** or 154,694.03504488856.(*only if my claim is correct, though*).

You can watch this video by "WOW MATH", check also their references, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pkyg0dL3ddA

That's all. VOTE RASTAMAN. Thanks.